# Continue where left off in google doc viewer for reading pdfs

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, pdf, pdf-viewer

I want to continue reading a pdf where I had left off, need to record reading progress of google doc viewer. I have tried following-

```
 <iframe style="width:100%;min-height:600px; margin-top:84px;"
   src="https://docs.google.com/viewerng/viewer?url=https://www.learningcontainer.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/09/sample-pdf-download-10-mb.pdf&embedded=true#:0.page.2">
       </iframe>
```

using hash value is not working. Is there any other working solution?

Answer (score 0):

I tried replicating your scenario and based on what I found out, page parameter in the link is no longer existing in the current setting of Google doc viewer. Once you left the file and then access it again, it will always go to the first page by default.

You can check the HTTP header of your file through clicking CTRL + SHIFT + i. You can see in one of the options on the side the ***presspage?id***, and when you click it, you can see in the Request URL the token next to ***presspage?id***. This token is always newly generated every time the page is loaded.

Comment: Thanks, is there any way to add this required functionality?